# Handle multipart/form-data with Serverless?

Tags: multipartform-data, serverless-framework

How to handle multipart/form-data with serverless-framework? v.0.5.6

Just tried this:

```
"requestTemplates": {
        "multipart/form-data": {
          "httpMethod": "$context.httpMethod",
          "body": "$input.json('$')",
          "queryParams": "$input.params().querystring",
          "headerParams": "$input.params().header",
          "headerParamNames": "$input.params().header.keySet()",
          "contentTypeValue": "$input.params().header.get('Content-Type')"
        },
        "application/json": {
          "httpMethod": "$context.httpMethod",
          "body": "$input.json('$')",
          "queryParams": "$input.params().querystring",
          "headerParams": "$input.params().header",
          "headerParamNames": "$input.params().header.keySet()",
          "contentTypeValue": "$input.params().header.get('Content-Type')"
        }
      }
```

action.js:

```
export function respond(event, cb) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(event, function(err, fields, files) {
        if (err == null) {
            var response = {
                status: "true",
                data: fields,
                error: []
            };
            return cb(null, response);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            return cb(null, ApiErrors.errors(402, err['message'] + fields));
        }
    });



}
```

But got an error: `errorMessage = "Cannot read property 'content-length' of undefined";`

Comment: If `event` is a regular Lambda event, then the form is already parsed for you. Parsing input from a request is a part of the request template. So that responsibility falls on API Gateway, not Lambda.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I couldnt make it as multipart/form-data, so I used base64 string.

action.js:

```
export function respond(event, cb) {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    var key = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10) + '/' + String(Date.now());
    var contentType = event.body["data"].substr(0, event.body["data"].indexOf(';'));

    if (!contentType.match(/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i)) {
        return cb(null, 'invalid content type, gif, jpg, and png supported');
    }
    var data = new Buffer(event.body["data"].replace(/^image\/\w+;base64,/, ''),'base64');

    var params = {
        Bucket: 'your-bucket',
        Key: key,
        Body: data,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: contentType,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return cb(null, ApiErrors.errors(402, err['message']));
        } else {
            var response = {
                status: "true",
                data: {
                    url: urlPrefix + key
                },
                error: []
            };
            return cb(null, response);
        }
    });

}
```

RequestTemplate:

```
"requestTemplates": {
        "application/json": {
          "httpMethod": "$context.httpMethod",
          "body": "$input.json('$')",
          "header": "$input.params().header.get($header)",
          "headerParam": "$input.params().header.keySet()",
          "contentType": "$input.params().header.get('Content-Type')"
        }
      },
```

Comment: @GurpreetSinghDrish, that solution was to serverless 0.5. Nowadays its totally different.

Answer (score 9):

I've got this working with [serverless](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/) by emulating [http.ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) and using a form parser tool like [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable).

I'm using `lambda-proxy` for the API Gateway event configuration.

```
const Stream      = require('stream').Readable;
const Formidable  = require('formidable');

module.exports.upload = ( e, ctx, cb ) => {
    let form = new Formidable.IncomingForm();

    let stream = new Stream();
    stream.push( e.body );
    stream.push( null );

    // NOTE: You'll likely want to toLowerCase() at least 'Content-Type' header key
    stream.headers = e.headers;

    form.parse( stream, (err, fields, files) => {
        // Work with your parsed form results here.
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to manually set `e.headers['content-length'] = e.body.length;` otherwise the dummyParser would be used!